# User question to find similar word from the document. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'similarity_search'

Tags: python

```
query = st.text_input("ask questions about your pdf")

st.write(VectorStore)
#st.write(query)

if query:
    docs = VectorStore.similarity_search(query=query)# in this place error happening
    print(f"Loaded VectorStore: {VectorStore}")
    st.write(docs)
```

Comment: What is *VectorStore* (obvioyusly it's *None* but where is it initialized)? Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.